# How to build SML/NJ executable on Mac

Tags: macos, smlnj

I have an SML/NJ program that I can run as a heap image, and I want to create a standalone executable binary.  However, the `heap2exec` tool in SML/NJ 110.73 always yields errors for me.

I created my heap image `tigerc.x86-darwin` via the following:

```
ml-build sources.cm Main.main tigerc
```

I can run my program fine using the heap image via

```
sml @SMLload=tigerc.x86-darwin
```

I should be able to create the standalone binary via

```
heap2exec tigerc.x86-darwin tigerc
```

but that generates the error

```
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specificed, assuming 10.7
ld: warning: ignoring file tigerc.o, file was built for unsupported file format 
which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

I looked at the `heap2exec` shell script, and the key lines (variable-expanded) do the following:

```
heap2asm "$heapfile" "$execfile".s
cc -c -o "$execfile".o "$execfile".s
ld -o "$execfile" ${RUNX} "$execfile".o
```

When I run these steps individually, the `cc` command generates an x86_64 `.o` file, but the `ld` command is trying to link an i386 executable.  So I need to convince the `cc` command to generate an i386 `.o` file as well.

Is there a way to set an environment variable to get `cc` to build i386 instead of x86_84?  (`ARCH` doesn't do the trick, by the way — it's already set to `i386`.)

Or is there another workaround to get `heap2exec` to generate the right architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `CFLAGS=-m32` as an environment variable.  That's the standard way to force it to build a 32-bit object file.

I know you're asking specifically about SML/NJ, but MLton has 64-bit support and makes this kind of task really easy.  You might thank yourself later if you're in a position to use it to generate executable binaries instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, CFLAGS is ignored by the SML/NJ heap2exec script.